# I have a problem with my symfony project when I try to exit()

Tags: symfony4

I was trying to add data into the doctrine using:

```
 $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $user = new User();
 $user->setName('Oamogetswe');
 $entityManager->persist($user);
 exit($entityManager->flush());
```

But all I am getting is a `An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver error message`. I am using SQLITE3

Comment: 1. Check if Database extension is installed/enabled
2. Check for the connection, whether or not it is correctly configured.

Comment: Hi Rohan, looks like my Database extension and PHP extensions weren't setup. Thanks alot, I managed to have the problem fixed.